# How do you get params from the URL in Vue/Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Using Nuxt I have a page `pages/works/[author]/[title].vue`, with a backend API at `localhost:8000/api/works/<author>/<title>`.

This works:

```
<script setup>    
const {data: content} = await useFetch('http://localhost:8000/api/works/SomeAuthor/SomeTitle')     
</script>
```

If I try to make it dynamic like

```
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const route = useRoute();

const url = config.apiUrl + '/api/works/' + route.params.author + '/' + route.params.title;

console.log('url is' + url); // Seems ok

const {data: content } = await useFetch(url);  // Errors
```

It breaks, I get 4 lines of

```
[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/works/SomeAuthor/undefined/api/works/SomeAuthor/SomeTitle"
```

What could be causing it? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you don’t have a problem getting the route params and it should work fine, but the error is within the path it self.
**works/SomeAuthor/undefined/api/works/SomeAuthor/SomeTitle**

You are getting a repeated path, and it shouldn’t be like this.
Maybe the problem with your folder structure? Or the apiUrl?
If you can provide the code, I can take a look and give more help.

**Answer:**

In your nuxt.config add run time config:

```
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      url: process.env.HTTP_API_BASE_URL,
    },
  }
```

then in your component get the url like that:

```
const baseURL = useRuntimeConfig().url
const route = useRoute()
const {data: content } = await useFetch(baseURL + route.params.author + route.params.title)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The API is actually running separately on localhost:8000 using Python. In my `nuxt.config.ts` I have:  


```

  runtimeConfig: {  
    apiUrl: process.env.API\_URL  
  } 

```  


I noticed that from the terminal where I run `yarn dev`, it's able to properly `console.log(config.apiUrl)`, whereas on the browser developer tools console, it shows up as undefined which I assume is because in `runtimeConfig` it is not under `public`;

Comment: if it can be done only server-side, is there some other setting that I should be looking at?

Is there also some way to pinpoint how/why it constructs a request like that starts with `/works/SomeAuthor/undefined`? Does it somehow interpret `config.apiUrl` as that with `title` as undefined, before appending `/api/works/SomeAuthor/SomeTitle`?

Comment: i have edited my answer, please try it

Answer (score 0):

Please check the index.js/router.js to see if the route is accepting Params.

If so, check the following things :

1. Check if route.params is populated:
   Make sure that route.params contains the expected values. You can use `console.log(route.params) to inspect the values of author and title`
2. Check for URL encoding issues:
   If route.params.title contains special characters, you might want to ensure that it's properly URL encoded before appending it to the URL. You can use encodeURIComponent for this purpose (I dont think this is the problem):

   const url = config.apiUrl + '/api/works/' + route.params.author + '/' + encodeURIComponent(route.params.title);